# Windows 10 keeps adding Spansh as keyboard language and switching to it

Tags: windows-10, keyboard, language

I've Windows 10 Home Single Language Version 1803 and only `Spanish Uruguay - Latinoamerican Keyboard` language configured in the region section of settings. 
But windows keeps adding a Spanish language and keeps changing to it in many times and it's reaaaly annoying. 
What do I have to do to remove this language??
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Do you by chance of a Windows 10 Home Single Language license?

Comment: @Ramhound yes, I've got that licence.. why?

Comment: Because the license only allows a single language pack to be installed which cannot be changed.  Edit your question to provide the relevant information required to answer your question.

Comment: But the display language is one thing and the keyboard layout is another...

Comment: display language is independent of the language pack always has been

Answer (score -1):

Have you ever tried to remove it with PowerShell？ If not, follow these steps：

1. Open Windows PowerShell and select **Run as Administrator**.
2. Type the following command to list the languages currently installed on the device, and then press ENTER: **Get-winuserlanguagelist** (as shown in your own screenshot).
3. Note the languagetag you want to delete.
4. Type the following command (one at a time) to remove the unwanted language, and then press **ENTER**:

   **$LangList = Get-WinUserLanguageList**

   **$MarkedLang = $LangList | where LanguageTag -eq "LANGUAGETAG"**

   **$LangList.Remove($MarkedLang)**

   **Set-WinUserLanguageList $LangList -Force**

**Note:** In the second command, make sure that you change the Languagetag using the code for the language you want to delete. For example, es-UY.

After you complete these steps, open the Settings app in the **Regions and Languages** page, and the languages that you cannot delete before should disappear.

If you try to delete the primary language, remember that you must set the new language to the new default language before the **Delete** button is available.

Hope the above information can help you.